# Whats the advantage of having Weapon as an interface over Abstract class

Tags: java, oop

[image]

problem Statement : Warriors fight with weapon in the battle field.

Taking the situation in the image,

say, we have a class warrior which implements Weapons .

Weapon may extend to sword, gun , etc.

I have a confusion, whether Weapon should be a interface or an abstract class.

If it needs to be an interface, whats the advantage over it.

[Edit]

If it is an interface I believe implementation will be like this.

```
Weapon myWeapon;
myWeapon = new Sword();
```

Comment: Why would `myWarrior` be a sword? Warriors are not, on the whole, swords.

Comment: This type of question are much better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You need to rethink your class design as well as what your interfaces mean.

Comment: Multiple Inheritance, what if you wield a spiked shield? You can bash people with it. Is it a Weapon or a Shield?

Comment: Warrior needs to use weapon to fight in the battle field. And weapon can be anything. Hence made it as an interface

Comment: @Andre .. Thats what its confusing me.. Multiple inheritance is not allowed in Java. And by using interface, we are indirectly achieving it. Is this the advantage ?

Even if Weapon is an abstract class, we can achieve the same right ?

Comment: @srinath the big problem with multiple inheritance comes in calling parent constructors, see https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/ . Interfaces allow a limited form of multiple inheritance, but since interfaces can't have constructors, we avoid this problem.

Comment: With this relationship you should be thinking about a "has a" relationship, not "is a".

Comment: I am really sorry, there was a big typo.. I thought its Weapon and i typed Warrior :P. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So first - Warrior should not implement Weapon definitely.**

Implementing an interface or extending a class is an ***IS A*** relationship. Gun is a Weapon, but Warrior is not. He just uses a Weapon, which is a *composition* - a ***HAS A*** relationship.

**Weapon should probably be an interface**

Interface is something that tells what can be done with the object of a class implementing that interface. It doesn't tell how it is achieved. This separation is good for your clean design.

If there is any common behavior that all weapons or some of them share, you can introduce an abstract class that in hierarchy could stand between interface and concrete implementation. Note here (this is a common mistake) that behavior does not mean adding a new method. So if you think for instance that a gun can be reloaded, so it needs another method for it, the abstract class can't help here. In this case you could introduce another interface, like *Reloadable* and make Gun implement both Weapon and Reloadable. The common behavior is just when some concrete classes implement some interface method in same or similar way. The abstract class could then implement this one method but leave the rest not implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that a warrior is not a weapon but rather uses the weapon... ;-)

- Use an **abstract class** if you have **common code** you want all your weapons to have. For example a method to break the weapon if it has been used to often.
- An **interface** is only a template so to speak <del>and **can't have the implementation in itself**</del>. (See comment below: Default implementation.)
- Also a class can have **multiple interfaces** but there is **no diamond inheritance** in Java so you only have exactly one base class.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Just saw... I have corrected this. Is it clear now how I mean this?

Comment: [This is what I was referring to.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html). Not sure we're on the same page?

Comment: Sorry.. it was a typo .. Corrected it

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I do java for almost 10 years and didn't know the default implementation. Thx. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Actually default methods were introduced in Java 8, so not that long time ago. Btw, this also enables multiple inheritance possibility and btw, this is not the same as Diamond of Death that was possible in C++. Java 8 has contracts that prevent this possibility.

Comment: Glad you learned something. Yes, it's new so don't feel bad, the comment that said that was deleted. :)